# Passing data from multidimensional array in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array that looks like:

```
[Category(title: "First Category", question: [
     Question(
 title: "1 Question",
 article: "1 Arcticle",
 anwser: "Answer",
 link: "google.com",
 favorite: false,
 possibleAnswers: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"],
 rightAnswerNumber: 2), etc..]),
etc..]
```

I don't understand how to extract data in next ViewController. Here I have  a code
In parent:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == ListViewController.className() {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ListViewController
        var data: Category
        if isFiltering() {
            data = filteredData[indexPath!.row]
        } else {
            data = dataSource[indexPath!.row]
        }
        destinationVC?.passedData = data
    }
}
```

In child:

```
var passedData: Category?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ListTableViewCell.identifier(), for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell
    cell.passedData = passedData![indexPath.row][indexPath.row] //Here
    cell.selectionStyle = .gray
    return cell

}
```

I need to make cell.passedData take an array of Question in Category depends from indexPath, but don't know how.

I was thinking about extracting array from Category using for loop, but didn't realize how.

Comment: what is the type of `cell.passedData`?

Comment: I am passing exact single Category because I need to display title of Category and have array of Question to display in TableView. In first VC I have an array of Categories that same load titles in TableView and depends on selection passing data of Category (title, array of Questions) in next VC.

Comment: Is `cell.passedData`of type `Question` or `String`?

Comment: cell.passedData is Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `passedData` of the child view controller has a type of `Category`, you just need to replace

```
cell.passedData = passedData![indexPath.row][indexPath.row] //Here
```

with

```
cell.passedData = passedData!.question[indexPath.row]
```

in the child view controller

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple, my fault that I didn't realize that!